# template deduction failed in vector

Tags: c++, c++11

I try to make a generic cross product function :

```
template<class ContainerType1, class ContainerType2, typename ReturnType>
std::vector<ReturnType> cross_product(const ContainerType1& a, const ContainerType2& b) 
{
  assert((a.size()==3)&&(b.size==3));

  return {a[1]*b[2]-a[2]-b[1], a[2]*b[0]-a[0]*b[2], a[0]*b[1]-a[1]*b[0]};
}
```

the line

```
std::vector<double> A = cross_product(p_r2,p_r1);
```

give me the error :

```
error : couldn't deduce template parameter ‘ReturnType’
```

Is there a way to keep the genericity, and avoid to declare ReturnType as, for example, double ?

Comment: `b.size` --> `b.size()` - And perhaps it'd be better to use a container with static size. Because that assertion may be removed

Comment: that's a first mistake, thanks. For the static size container, maybe ... i have to look at that ... But my initial problem stay the same.

Comment: also `a[1]*b[2]-a[2]-b[1]` has different operations to `a[2]*b[0]-a[0]*b[2]` and `a[0]*b[1]-a[1]*b[0]` (two subtractions vs two multiplications)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your container types follow the design of the standard library, they will have a `value_type` member alias. You can deduce [the common type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) from that:

```
template<class ContainerType1, class ContainerType2>
auto cross_product(const ContainerType1& a, const ContainerType2& b) ->
    std::vector<
        typename std::common_type<
            typename ContainerType1::value_type,
            typename ContainerType2::value_type
        >::type
    >
{
    assert((a.size()==3) && (b.size()==3));
    return {a[1]*b[2]-a[2]-b[1], a[2]*b[0]-a[0]*b[2], a[0]*b[1]-a[1]*b[0]};
}
```

Comment: Note the difference between `std::common_type` and `decltype`, integral promotion, and "custom" type which has wanted operator but not necessary the common type (`complex<T>`).

Comment: @Jarod42 - `std::common_type` is specified in terms of `?:`. For class types like `std::complex` it [will try to find an implicit conversion sequence](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35620cde9c34e684).

Comment: But yeah, heavy duty gun compared to simply using decltype.

Comment: `char`/`char` would do `char` for you, `int` with `decltype`. and for custom type, `complex` was a (bad?) example, whereas `common_type` of `complex<float>` and `double` works, `operator*` fails (so difference between both again ;-) ).

Answer (score 10):

Consider using [Class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction), and writing:

```
template<class ContainerType1, class ContainerType2>
auto cross_product(const ContainerType1& a, const ContainerType2& b) 
{
  assert((a.size()==3)&&(b.size()==3));

  return std::vector{a[1]*b[2]-a[2]-b[1], a[2]*b[0]-a[0]*b[2], a[0]*b[1]-a[1]*b[0]};
}
```

Or, before C++ 17, using `decltype` to get the type of the values:

```
template<class ContainerType1, class ContainerType2>
auto cross_product(const ContainerType1& a, const ContainerType2& b)
    -> std::vector<decltype(a[0] * b[0] - a[0] - b[0])>
{
  assert((a.size()==3)&&(b.size()==3));

  return {a[1]*b[2]-a[2]-b[1], a[2]*b[0]-a[0]*b[2], a[0]*b[1]-a[1]*b[0]};
}
```

Comment: The C++11 solution is a very nice alternative to the exceptionally heavy gun my mind jumped to.